# How to extract Active Directory configuration?

Tags: active-directory

Is there a tool to extract AD configuration, which can be used later to perform technical configuration security audit without having any interaction with the machine that contain the AD?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this could be a solution :

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc463526%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

But there are many tools to export the objects of a AD and replicate to other TEST domain. I think you need only the export, right ?>

Comment: Welcome to SU. While the link might provide the answer it can become outdated or removed. In your answer could you provide the key points which answer the question and use the link as a source. Thanks.